# Nvidia update problems

Tags: drivers, nvidia

```
Jul 20 08:21:05 william-FK522AA-ABA-a6544f kernel: [609500.858664] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 390.77, but  
Jul 20 08:21:05 william-FK522AA-ABA-a6544f kernel: [609500.858664] NVRM: this kernel module has the version 390.67.  Please  
Jul 20 08:21:05 william-FK522AA-ABA-a6544f kernel: [609500.858664] NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver  
Jul 20 08:21:05 william-FK522AA-ABA-a6544f kernel: [609500.858664] NVRM: components have the same version.
```

Comment: Might sound like a silly question, but did you restart after you updated?  In most cases, if I involve nvidia-smi for example, I'll get a version mismatch error until I restart.

Comment: I agree with @hiigaran.  I too have experienced that before until a reboot happened.  The new driver is not loaded until a reboot, so the older driver still has hold until the reboot is performed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purge all of the nvidia stuff first:

```
sudo apt purge ^nvidia
```

Install recommended Ubuntu Nvidia driver:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

After reboot check Nvidia driver in use:

```
nvidia-smi
```

**Remark.** If your Nvidia card is supported by 396 version nvidia driver, consider installing it from [Proprietary GPU Drivers repository](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Just execute before nvidia drivers clean up:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your reply. Yes, I followed all protocols that the update app instructed me to follow. The 'Nvidia X Server Settings' app is working once again. As I recall I originally installed the driver from the Proprietary site, as it was suggested to do the install that way. Also the System Settings app is now working Much Thanks for the assist, cannot beat the quick help here!!

Comment: @william As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If one of the answers *solved your problem*, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is the most useful of all](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**